# Can 가게 앞에 mean both 'at the front of the shop' (inside) and 'in front of the shop'?

Tags: word-usage

In English, if something is 'in front of the shop', it is outside the shop at the front side.

If it's 'at the front of the shop', it's at the front side, but could be outside or inside.

Can '아이스크림은 가게 앞에 있어요' be valid for both the case when the ice creams are outside and when they are inside?

If so, what's the shortest way to unambiguously say 'in front of' and 'inside, at the front'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, the differentiation is both in the preposition *in* and in the absence or presence of *the*.

Korean uses context to disambiguate, but the *default* context with 가게 앞 is outside the shop at the front side. This may not be the same for all nouns, and it is a matter of "assumed cultural" semantic knowledge to know which refers to which.

There is the word **앞쪽** which more often than not refers to the "fore" of an object. I'd put it with something to disambiguate the interior of the shop, something like 가게 안, usually in a separate clause (가게 안으로 가서...).

If you're feeling particularly literary and want something really condensed, 점내(店內) is a Sino-Korean word of rather low frequency for "the interior of the shop". Best suited to the written word, if you ask me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe ".. 앞" almost always means "in front of".

I think maybe you could use it to mean "at the front section of" if the context makes it really clear, but I can't think of a good example right now.